# How to vectorize this five-point difference code to fast calculate derivatives of a matrix?

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, vectorization, difference

I am trying to calculate the partial first derivatives with respect to each of the two dimensions in a 2D matrix, i.e dF/dx and dF/dy, using the [five point method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation#Other_methods). I have managed to do this successfully by looping over the points:

```
dF_dx = zeros(size(F));
dF_dy = zeros(size(F));

% Derivative with respect to y for each x value (Apply to all columns simultaneously)
dF_dy(2,1:(Nx-1)) = ( F(3,1:(Nx-1)) - F(1,1:(Nx-1)) )/(2*dy);
for m = 3:(Ny-2)
    dF_dy(m,1:(Nx-1)) = ( F(m-2,1:(Nx-1)) - F(m+2,1:(Nx-1)) + 8*F(m+1,1:(Nx-1)) - 8*F(m-1,1:(Nx-1)) )/(12*dy);
end
dF_dy(Ny-1,1:(Nx-1)) = ( F(Ny,1:(Nx-1)) - F(Ny-2,1:(Nx-1)) )/(2*dy);

% Derivative with respect to x for each y value (Apply to all rows simultaneously)
dF_dx(2:(Ny-1),2) = ( F(2:(Ny-1),3) - F(2:(Ny-1),1) )/(2*dx);
for n = 3:(Nx-2)
    dF_dx(2:(Ny-1),n) = ( F(2:(Ny-1),n-2) - F(2:(Ny-1),n+2) + 8*F(2:(Ny-1),n+1) - 8*F(2:(Ny-1),n-1) )/(12*dx);
end
dF_dx(2:(Ny-1),(Nx-1)) = ( F(2:(Ny-1),Nx) - F(2:(Ny-1),Nx-2) )/(2*dx);
```

Is there a clever Matlab way to vectorize this to make it much faster to execute? I have read several functions which seem like they might do the trick (such as [diff()](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html), [circshift()](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/circshift.html), or maybe even [kron()](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html) ), but am not sure how they might be used to solve this problem.

(My plan is to the implement this as a gpuArray later, if that is relevant for the solution).

Thank you!

---

### 1st Edit

By looking at the source code for [gradient()](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gradient.html), I was able to make the following version which is vectorized (i.e without the loop):

```
F = rand(5,8);
Nx = size(F,2);
Ny = size(F,1);
dx = 2;
dy = 3;

dF_dx = zeros(size(F));
dF_dy = zeros(size(F));

dF_dx(2:(Ny-1),3:Nx-2) = (F(2:(Ny-1),1:Nx-4) - F(2:(Ny-1),5:Nx) + 8*F(2:(Ny-1),4:Nx-1) - 8*F(2:(Ny-1),2:Nx-3))/(12*dx);
dF_dx(2:(Ny-1),2) = ( F(2:(Ny-1),3) - F(2:(Ny-1),1) )/(2*dx);
dF_dx(2:(Ny-1),(Nx-1)) = ( F(2:(Ny-1),Nx) - F(2:(Ny-1),Nx-2) )/(2*dx);

dF_dy(3:Ny-2,1:(Nx-1)) = (F(1:Ny-4,1:(Nx-1)) - F(5:Ny,1:(Nx-1)) + 8*F(4:Ny-1,1:(Nx-1)) - 8*F(2:Ny-3,1:(Nx-1)))/(12*dy);
dF_dy(2,1:(Nx-1)) = ( F(3,1:(Nx-1)) - F(1,1:(Nx-1)) )/(2*dy);
dF_dy((Ny-1),1:(Nx-1)) = ( F(Ny,1:(Nx-1)) - F(Ny-2,1:(Nx-1)) )/(2*dy);
```

Is there a way to do it without all the indexing (which I suspect is what is taking the most time)?

---

### 2nd Edit

I have now implemented Cris and chtz's suggestion and achieved this using a convolution with `conv2()`, as follows:

```
F = rand(500,600);
Nx = size(F,2);
Ny = size(F,1);
dx = 2;
dy = 3;

 [dF_dx, dF_dy] = partial_derivatives(F, dx, dy, Nx, Ny)


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
function [dF_dx, dF_dy] = partial_derivatives(F, dx, dy, Nx, Ny)

kernx = [-1 8 0 -8 1]/(12*dx); % Convolution kernel for x dimension
kerny = [-1;8;0;-8;1]/(12*dy); % Convolution kernel for y dimension

%%%%%%%% Partial derivative across x dimension %%%%%%%%
dF_dx = conv2(F, kernx, 'same') ; % Internal mesh points (five-point method)

% Second and penultimate mesh points (two-point method)
dF_dx(2:(Ny-1),2) = ( F(2:(Ny-1),3) - F(2:(Ny-1),1) )/(2*dx);
dF_dx(2:(Ny-1),(Nx-1)) = ( F(2:(Ny-1),Nx) - F(2:(Ny-1),Nx-2) )/(2*dx);
dF_dx(:,[1 Nx]) = 0; % Set boundary conditions
dF_dx([1 Ny],:) = 0; %


%%%%%%%% Partial derivative across x dimension %%%%%%%%
dF_dy = conv2(F, kerny, 'same') ; % Internal mesh points (five-point method)

% Second and penultimate mesh points (two-point method)
dF_dy(2,1:(Nx-1)) = ( F(3,1:(Nx-1)) - F(1,1:(Nx-1)) )/(2*dy);
dF_dy((Ny-1),1:(Nx-1)) = ( F(Ny,1:(Nx-1)) - F(Ny-2,1:(Nx-1)) )/(2*dy);
dF_dy(:,Nx) = 0;     % Set boundary conditions
dF_dy([1 Ny],:) = 0; %

end
```

As a gpuArray, this does not provide any noticable improvement over the vectorized version in the 1st Edit. Is there an obvious way to improve it? Thanks.

Comment: Did you have a look at [`conv2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html)?

Comment: No, I didn't. That's another one then to add to the list of possible ways to go!

Comment: The indexing itself is not the cause of the slowdown, but rather making all those copies of most of the array. Your equation requires 5 copies of the array to be weighted and added. Chtz’s suggestion of using a convolution is the right way to go.

Comment: @Cris Luengo thanks both, I will pursue the convolution approach. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I have done as you suggested - see my 2nd Edit. Is this what you had in mind? It gives the correct result, but doesn't show any improvement. Can you see how I might proceed / what to try next? Thanks for your support.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Notice that I have still used a two point indexed method for the second and penultimate points in the mesh, near the edges.

Comment: Why do you feel that the edge results of `conv2` are wrong and need correcting? Why do you think your partial kernel is the better solution?

Comment: That's a good question, and now that you ask I don't have a good answer!  I suppose just because I'm accustomed to not using the 5 point stencil on those points, because we would typically use a 2 point method here. I have therefore overwritten those points in the result of conv2 to be sure I know exactly what the values are. I am not sure what the direct conv2 values represent at those points when supplying a 5 point kernel.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Can the convolution method be used in the case where we have a non-uniform grid? The current method above specifies dx and dy as constants in the kernals.If so, could you hint at how I might achieve that? Thank you!

Comment: What is a non-uniform grid? Does the grid spacing vary? Or does it have different spacing along the various dimensions?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Sorry. Yes, I mean the grid spacing varies, so that the separation between grid points is different. For example, the x vector might be x = [0 1 1.5 4 10]. The y vector need not necessarily be the same, e.g y = [0 10 50 55 70]. Do you think the convolution method could be adapted to accomodate this?

Comment: No, I don’t think you’ll find any existing implementations for your case, you’ll likely have to implement the convolution yourself. Normalization is a bit different in this case, not complicated, just different.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thanks, I see. When you say "implement it myself", do you mean I simply couldnt use conv2(), but would need to do it with the built in FFT function. Or do you mean even the FFT couldnt be used in this case, and I would have to evaluate the discrete sum? Any tips to the rough steps involved would be great - I'm not sure where to start. Thanks again.